# pass an argument that may not be set to a function, without throwing a notice

Tags: php, function, parameters

PHP has the `isset()` function, that takes a variable, and tells you whether it was set.  It doesn't throw a notice when passed an array key that doesn't exist.  I'd like to duplicate that functionality in a new function that does something like this:

```
function my_function($arg1, $arg2) {
    if(isset($arg1)) {
        //...do something
    } else {
        //...do something else
    }
}
```

or eventually something like this:

```
function my_function() {
    $arglist = func_get_args();
    foreach($arglist as $arg) {
        if(isset($arg)) {
            // ... do something
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, these functions won't work.  I could suppress all errors with @, and then just test for null, but I'd prefer to leave error reporting intact.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after extensive fooling around, based on the answers given, I found a solution!

The issue is one of scope, and the error-checking occurs at the moment of assignment, when you call a function with values.

**HOWEVER**

If you pass your variables by reference, error checking is not triggered!  In fact, the references are passed, and errors are thrown at the first bad use, *inside* the function!

```
// returns an HTML-safe version of the first defined, non-falsey argument
function print_OR(&$highp = null, &$lowp = null, &$default=null) {
    if(isset($highp)&&($highp||$highp===0)) return htmlspecialchars($highp);
    if(isset($lowp )&&($lowp ||$lowp ===0)) return htmlspecialchars($lowp);
    return htmlspecialchars($default);
}
```

Here are a set of tests, showing this as functional: http://pastebin.com/C9QTvSi7

Comment: That's one of the various ways to work around that which I talked about. However, this *creates* the variables in the calling scope if they didn't exist. It's a solution with side effects! Not good.

Comment: @deceze is partially right (as of PHP 7).  If you pass some random unset variable `$foo`, it does not become set.  But if you pass in an unset array element `$foo['bar']`, `$foo` gets set.  the status of `$foo['bar']` is a bit fuzzy: if you `print_r( $foo )` it shows an empty 'bar' element; but if you `isset( $foo['bar'] )` it returns false.  So my best guess is $foo['bar'] is set to NULL and isset returns false for something with a NULL value.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign default values to the parameters and then check to see if they are set to their default values when the function is called. In this case I used `null`:

```
function my_function($arg1=null, $arg2=null) {
    if(!is_null($arg1)) {
        //...do something
    } else {
        //...do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't prevent the notice from being thrown.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the test code: http://pastebin.com/E3FX6EMA  and a screenshot of the results: http://imgur.com/upKYpCK

Comment: This function has no effect on those errors you see because they are outside the scope of it. You're trying to use them *before* you validate them inside of the function. You need to catch them *before* you try to use them in this function.

Comment: yes, but that is the whole point of this question.  I'm trying to make a function that, like `isset()` will NOT throw these notices when called, so that I can handle them in-function.  If I need to test which of these is initialized before calling the function, the function is worthless.

Comment: Not sure it's possible. You're looking for errors after the fact. PHP just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_function($arg1, $arg2) {
```

Inside this function, `$arg1` and `$arg2` will always be *set*, because you declared those variables in the function signature. Checking for `isset` inside this function is pointless.

When calling this function, you're passing some completely different variable into it:

```
my_function($foo, $bar);
```

I'm guessing you want to avoid having to check whether `$foo` or `$bar` are *set* in the calling scope. This is not possible. `$foo` is a different variable than `$arg1`. You need to check whether `$foo` isset in the scope in which `$foo` is supposed to exist, `my_function` has nothing to do with that scope.

```
function my_function($arg1) {
    if (isset($arg1)) ...
}

my_function($foo);
              ^
              |
              +--- error is thrown here, code inside my_function can't help
```

There may be all sorts of elaborate ways to avoid having to write `isset`, but don't go there. Write `isset` where it's necessary, avoid having to write `isset` by properly declaring your variables where they should exist.

```
my_function(isset($foo) ? $foo : null);
```

In fact, the only time you really can't know whether entire variables are set is for user input, mostly through `$_POST` or `$_GET`. For those you have to check. Any other variable inside your application you have full control over and can ensure that they exist where they should exist.

Comment: Then logically, how does `isset($my_array['bad_key'])` itself work?  I am calling a function with an argument that is bad.  A notice should be thrown before I enter `isset()`'s scope.  So, either `isset()` is a hard coded anomaly that doesn't follow any of the scope rules, or there is in fact a mechanism to accomplish this.

Comment: Indeed, `isset` is a "hardcoded anomaly". PHP would call it a *language construct* instead of a function. Think of it more like a built-in operator like `*`, `new` or `instanceof` instead of a function. See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: You are correct about `isset` not being a real function, but it turns out there actually is a solution to my question.  You can avoid the notice by passing as reference.  The notice is then thrown at the first bad call within the function.  see my answer for code and tests. :)