# PHP prevent warning about undefined $_POST

Tags: php

I have a function I wrote in PHP that checks that the passed in parameters are defined and not empty:

```
Functions::check_required_parameters(array($_POST['id']));
```

The problem though, is if `$_POST['id']` is not set at all, PHP throws a warning. I can use `@` in front of the function call to silence the warnings, but using `@` is frowned upon. Is there a way to do this without using `@` and without a warning?

I know I could also do:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    Functions::check_required_parameters(array($_POST['id']));
} else {
    Error::show(400, "Missing required parameter.");
}
```

But that requires adding 3 lines of code every single place `Functions::check_required_parameters()` is used.

#### Update

Here is the definition of `Functions::check_required_parameters()`:

```
    public static function check_required_parameters($params) {
        if(is_array($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                if(!isset($param) || empty($param)) {
                    if($param !== 0 && $param !== "0") {
                        Error::show(400, "Missing required parameter.");
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(!isset($params) || empty($params)) {
                if($param !== 0 && $param !== "0") {
                    Error::show(400, "Missing required parameter.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us defination of `check_required_parameters`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22637955/476

Comment: Also see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/). Your use of `isset` and `empty` is very misguided and nonsensical. Your two nested `if` checks can be replaced with one `if (!$param)`, and it will do pretty much the same.

Answer (score 2):

Going by your particular use case, I'd probably just change the signature for the check_required_parameters() function to the below, moving a check for isset inside the function itself:

```
check_required_parameters(array $arr, $key)
```

Then you could use the function as follows:

```
check_required_parameters($_POST, 'id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
Functions::check_required_parameters(array( 
  ( isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 0 )
);
```

I voluntarily added line returns for readability.

Or you could also intercept the $_POST array before any other operation and check if it is set with the example you gave:

```
if( !isset($_POST['id'] ){
  $_POST['id'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: The logic that returns the error is encapsulated inside of `Functions::check_required_parameters()` so if the parameter is not set, it is going to pass 0 into it right?

Comment: yes it is a ternary operator, if it is set, it returns the value, if not, 0; I also added a second part in my answer, but this require to create a function called before anything else, and every time.

Comment: I think doing `( isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : null )` as the argument into `check_required_parameters()` will work, but it is a huge amount of work, as sometimes I pass 7 or 8 arguments into `check_required_parameters()`. It is also error prone, and introduces a lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Yeah sure, I think that the idea to intercept the $_POST variable at each page reload is better.